# How do I plot a discrete array of points say [x1,...xn] on the x axis in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot

Suppose I have a set of points [x1,x2,...,xn] then how do I plot them on the real line? . The reason I am asking is that I want to plot the eigen values of a Gaussian Orthogonal Ensemble along the x axis. So using eig(A) , I get an array of size n(lets say 10) . So I want to plot those 10 points along the x axis. That is I simply want to plot these real numbers on the x-axis. It does not matter if I plot it on say the line y=1 . Given a pen and paper , I would just draw a line and mark them with dots. How do I do this on MATLAB?

Put even simply , I just want to plot [1,2,3,4,5] on the x axis with prominent dots.

So what I would ideally want is a prominent axis and prominent dots on it according to [x1,...,xn] and also display the labels .

Here is a picture [image]

What I have tried is

x=[1,2,3,4]
plot(x,0) or plot(x,1). But it shows just a blank graph. Can anyone help me out with this? I am an absolute noob in MATLAB.

I was expecting the line y=0 or y=1 with dots marking the points (1,0),(2,0),(3,0),(4,0) or (1,1),...,(4,1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> " I was expecting the line y=0 or y=1 with dots marking the points (1,0),(2,0),(3,0),(4,0) or (1,1),...,(4,1)."

The following script will do that:

```
hold('on')                                      % Do all plots in the same figure
axis([0,5,-0.1 1.1]);grid('on')                 % Set the axes and turn on the grid
x = 1:4                                         % x = [1 2 3 4]
plot(x,ones(size(x)),'b')                       % Line y=1
plot(x,zeros(size(x)),'b')                      % Line y=0
scatter(x,zeros(size(x)),'MarkerFaceColor','b') % Points: (1,0),(2,0),(3,0),(4,0)
scatter(x,ones(size(x)),'MarkerFaceColor','b')  % Points: (1,1),(2,1),(3,1),(4,1)
```

The result:

[image]